# Speed up time exporting phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I need a help, I have many reports with 10 to 30 columns and 20000 or more rows, mi driver is mongodb and the result query is very fast, but when a create a document sheet with library PHPExcel is too slow five or ten minutes approximately or some time more, my code has only one bucle:

```
    $row++;
    $contUser = 0;
    foreach ($data as $index => $objUser) {
        $backgroundColor = $colorOdd;
        if ($contUser % 2 == 0) {
            $backgroundColor = $colorPair;
        }
        $field = $objUser->getFields();
        $column = 0;
        //case 'N°':
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $contUser + 1);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));

        $column++;
        //case matricula:
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $objUser->getChrUsername());
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        //case matricula:
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $field['appaterno']['value']);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        //case matricula:
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $field['apmaterno']['value']);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        //case matricula:
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $objUser->getChrFirstname());
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));

        //$field['dni']['value']
        $column++;
        $type = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['dni']['value'], $type);
        //$sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        //$field['sociedad']['value']
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['sociedad']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['gerenciacentral']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['division']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['area']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['servicio']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['funcion']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['fecha']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['divpersonal']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['subpersonal']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['superior']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['matsuperior']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['estado']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['iniestado']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($field['finestado']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($objUser->getChrEmail(), $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit(empty($field['agencia']['value'])?'':$field['agencia']['value'], $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));

        $date = '';
        $time = '';
        if(!empty($this->lastAccessQuiz) && $this->lastAccessQuiz>0){
            $date = date("Y-m-d", $this->lastAccessQuiz);
            $time = date("H:i:s", $this->lastAccessQuiz);
        }
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($date, $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $column++;
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->setValueExplicit($time, $type);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($column)->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array('type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $backgroundColor)));
        $row++;
        $contUser++;
    }
```

Comment: Not possible to give an straight answer here, but let me say, i do many imports of huge data, and i thing for 20000+ rows is a time of 5-20min ok. If there a any bottlenecks that slow your script down, you have to find them. topic:xdebug with cachgrind and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with, don't set column styling (such as setAutoSizing true) for every single cell that you write.... write all your data, and then apply autosizing to that column.

Similarly with the cell styles.... they're all the same, so don't apply them to every individual cell, but apply to the entire range when you've finished writing the individual cells.
Where it's the background colour for a row, apply to the row range, but not every individual cell.